# Drupal 7: Feeds XPath Parser » Issues Multiple subitems and concat() not compatible

Tags: xpath, drupal-7, feed

I have following XML file:

```
<rows>
<row>
<title>Title 1</title>
<descriptions>
<description lang="EN">Lorem ipsum</description>
<description lang="FR">Lorem ipsum</description>
</descriptions>
</row>
<row>
<title>Title 2</title>
<descriptions>
<description lang="EN">Lorem ipsum</description>
<description lang="FR">Lorem ipsum</description>
</descriptions>
</row>
</rows>
```

I need to export @lang and the description as a string. (ex. "EN :: Lorem ipsum"). So I used the concat function for the xpath:

```
description = concat(.//description,' :: ',.//@lang)
```

This works well for the first description but ignores the second.

Is there a way to do this? NB `feeds_xpathparse` module only supports Xpath 1.0 functions.

Comment: There is no way to do this in XPath 1.0. You can either use XPath 2.0, or select all nodes and concatenate the results in your host language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this in XPath 1.0. You can either use XPath 2.0, or select all nodes and concatenate the results in your host language. –  helderdarocha

Answer (score 0):

If you've already the right context (e.g. `/row`), this syntax should work in FeedsXPathParserXML:

```
concat(description, " :: ", @lang)
```

The `concat()` is compatible with [XML XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-concat).